# Custom buttons on top of keyboard layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add some custom buttons for an EditText which sits on top of the android keyboard.
Just like in the image:
[image]

These buttons should hide when there is no keyboard

Comment: Taranfx please can you give any idea how to put layout just top of custom keyboard i am struggling with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a RelativeLayout with the property android:alignParentBottom="true".  This should keep any content you place with that property within the RelativeLayout at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I'm using LinearLayout for the complex design inside ScrollView.

Comment: What I am doing is using RelativeLayout as the root view, and putting everything I need inside of a LinearLayout with width and height = match_parent.  Put anything you need to "stick" to the bottom of the screen outside of the LinearLayout, in the root RelativeLayout with the attribute set as above

Comment: did that now, the button sits at the bottom of the screen but not on the top of the keyboard.

Comment: ahan got it to work, scrollview was stopping it from happening. Placed scrollview inside relative.